# Linux directory permissions read write but not delete

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Is it possible to setup directory permissions such that a group is able to read and write files and subdirectories but not delete anything?

Comment: I interpret "delete anything" to include prohibiting any modifications to existing files. Is that what you mean?

Do your users have direct filesystem access, or are they coming in via NFS, Samba, or some other route (FTP)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It might be enough to set the sticky bit on the directories. Users will be able to delete any files they own, but not those of other users.  This may be enough for your use case.  On most systems, /tmp is setup this way (/tmp is set 1777)

chmod 1775 /controlled

However, If you want more control, you'll have to enable ACL on the filesystem in question.

In /etc/fstab, append acl to the flags:

```
/dev/root        /                       ext3    defaults,acl       1 1
```

You can then use setfacl/getfacl to control and view acl level permissions.

Example: (Create files, once written, they are read only, but CAN be deleted by owner, but not others.)

```
setfacl --set u::rwxs,g::rwx /controlled
setfacl -d --set u::r-x,g::r-x,o::- /controlled
```

You can set a default acl list on a directory that will be used by all files created there.

As others have noted, be careful to specify exactly what you want. You say "write" - but can users overwrite their own files? Can they change existing content, or just append? Once written, it's read only?  Perhaps you can specify more detail in the comments.

Lastly, selinux and grsecurity provide even more control, but that's a whole other can of worms. It can be quite involved to setup.

Comment: Do you mean 1777 for /tmp?  The 4 indicates the SetUID bit (which only has meaning on a directory in BSD-derived systems, I believe).

Comment: I'm getting all kinds of errors running `setfacl --set u::rwxs,g::rwx /controlled` (where "/controlled" is the folder to be modified).  `setfacl -m u::rwx,g::rwx /controlled`

Comment: If the "1775" does not work (as it did not for me) I changed it to "1777" and it worked. This will make sure that everyone can write to the directory but cannot delete (and read) the other users files.

Answer (score 18):

Well, it would be r-x for this directory.

And files in it would have rw-.

This is because a file can be written if its permissions allow Write, but it can only be deleted if its *directory*'s permissions allow Write.

Comment: you also can't move files

Comment: Sticky bit is a pretty relevant as well.

Answer (score 3):

Possible or not, make sure that overwriting with a 0-byte file isn't equivalent to deleting the file in your particular context.

Comment: You can use 'chattr +a' which means "file can only be opened in append mode for writing", meaning you can't rewrite existing content, but you can add new content to the end. This should prevent truncation.

Comment: However chattr +a requires root access to set on new files.